# LWC DatePicker Error: moment is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement `datePicker` in LWC and referencing https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/08/convert-a-javascript-datepicker-to-a-lightning-web-component.html

I have stored `moment.js` in static resource and I have copy pasted from https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js and version is `Moment.js 2.29.1`

When I add below `datePickerApp` in page, it shows below image and throws error from function `loadActivities` from `js file`

> **[moment is not a function]**

[image]

`datePickerApp.html`

```
<template>
    <c-date-picker></c-date-picker>
</template>
```

`datePicker.js`

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import moment from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/moment';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class DatePicker extends LightningElement {
    lastClass;
    @track dateContext 
    @track selectedDate 
    @track dates = [];
    today

    connectedCallback(){
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, moment + '/moment.js')
          ]).then(() => {
           this.loadActivities();
        });
    }

    loadActivities(){
        this.today = moment();
        this.dateContext = moment();
        this.selectedDate = moment();
    }
}
```

`datePicker.html`

```
<template>
    <div class="dates">
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button class="link" type="button" onclick={goToday}>
                Today
            </button>
            <p>{formattedSelectedDate}</p>
            <p class="bold">{year}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button class="prev" type="button" onclick={previousMonth}>
                Prev
            </button>
            <span class="bold">{month}</span>
            <button class="next" type="button" onclick={nextMonth}>
                Next
            </button>
        </div>
        <ul class="header">
            <li>Sun</li>
            <li>Mon</li>
            <li>Tue</li>
            <li>Wed</li>
            <li>Thu</li>
            <li>Fri</li>
            <li>Sat</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="datePickerHolder">
            <template for:each={dates} for:item="date">
                <li
                    key={date.formatted}
                    class={date.className}
                    data-date={date.formatted}
                    onclick={setSelected}
                >
                    {date.text}
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `window.moment();`.

From [Exploring Salesforce Lightning Web Components: Part 4](https://john-tucker.medium.com/exploring-salesforce-lightning-web-components-part-4-cb40dd8b02bc):

> Similar to code within a Lighting Web Component, loaded scripts do not
> have access to the global *window* object; each has access to only a
> local component *window* object.

though I haven't found official documentation in the subject.

Comment: Good educated guess, but ultimately incorrect.

Comment: @sfdcfox Aren't these equivalents, with referencing `window.moment` directly having the advantage of no modification needed to the script file?

Comment: In a loadScript context, you'd be right, but native files need to include exports in order to access the contents. I included a link to a previous answer in my answer that goes into more demonstration.

Comment: This actually works for me. I am able to perform all the functions with `window.moment()`.

Comment: Doh. Sorry, looks like I misread the question. Silly me.